# Screen cut off on linux

Tags: linux, hdmi, resolution, tv

### Setup

- i5 6600
- Intel HD 530
- Internal SSD with Windows 11
- External HDD with Debian 12 (KDE Plasma, X11 and Wayland)
- Dp to HDMI dongle (Motherboard doesn't have HDMI and tv doesn't have DP)
- Old Majestic tv (TVD-224 LED)

### Issue

While on Windows everything is fine, on linux, if I set 1920x1080 resolution, the screen extends a little bit beyond the actual tv edges, just enough to make it unusable and very annoying.

If I start a X11 session, I run a simple script to set the maximum resolution that is not 1920x1080, otherwise KDE (just like every other environment) sets 1360x768.
However, if I'm in a Wayland session, my script fails. I tried changing HDMI-3 (my output name) to XWAYLAND0, to no avail.

Here are my scripts:

```
/// res.sh
#! /bin/bash

xrandr --newmode "1792x1008_60.00"  149.50  1792 1904 2088 2384  1008 1011 1016 1046 -hsync +vsync
    xrandr --addmode HDMI-3 "1792x1008_60.00"
    xrandr --output HDMI-3 --mode "1792x1008_60.00"
```

```
/// wayland_res.sh
#! /bin/bash

xrandr --newmode "1792x1008_60.00"  149.50  1792 1904 2088 2384  1008 1011 1016 1046 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "1792x1008_60.00"
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode "1792x1008_60.00"
```

I know I should buy a monitor, newer pc, ssd for linux, etc... but I currently can't.
I just need a solution to **at least** make the script run on Wayland.

I searched a bit online but didn't find anything related to my tv (it's not what pops up when you search it on google). I suspect everything is caused by overscanning, but again, didn't manage to find a manual and it's not even an option in the tv menu.

### Update

I realized that 1360x768 is not 16:9, so I tried to set 1280x720 to see if it would overscan the same way, and it did.
So my tv overscans every 16:9 resolution, but not 1792x1008.
This is not necessarely relevant, but it just shows how strange the situation is. I just need a way to run the script on Wayland, as I 1920x1080 is not absolutely necessary

Comment: Sounds like your TV does overscan. You should disable that.

Comment: As I said, I couldn't find anything on how to disable it

Comment: It's rarely called that. Sometimes you can enable "PC Mode" or something the like. I recommend you try again, it is the only way to do this without sacrificing resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately tv is quite old, and doesn't have any modes, only options are color profile (witch I tried changing, as a desperate attempt), noise reduction, and aspect ratio (only 16:9 and 4:3 present, nothing else). I tried messing with those, with no results. What I do not understand is why Windows manages to compensate just perfectly on 1920x1080, while linux does not

Comment: Last time I had to deal with a CRT that overscanned, I needed a proprietary nvidia driver that had over/underscan controls. but that was like 2007. I believe you can do it with xrandr.

Comment: have you tried `xrandr --set underscan on` or Pan/scan with `xrandr -q`